# What is the name of this maze generation algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, maze

I figured an algorithm for maze/labyrinth/map generation. I needed this algorithm for a platform game in which each location is randomly generated. I wanted to have multiple platforms with random blockages and connections between levels and have the possibility to visit every place on the map.

I’ve created some algorithm and figured that it is so simple and yet useful, it has to be some already known mechanism.

So if you know which wheel I reinvented please tell me.

Is my algorithm similar to any of the commonly used methods? What is the name of such an algorithm and how to find some studies/analysis of it?

The general idea is presented in the here:

[image: diagram].

Note: In the diagram, the maze path is depicted as a line, not the space between them.

Comment: This is basically Kruskal's algorithm on a graph that is connected like a lattice (i.e. each node has a neighbor to the top, left, bottom, right) with equal weights.

Comment: @alkasm I think you're right. Thanks :)

Comment: Probably a better place for this question in the future would be https://cs.stackexchange.com/ --- Stack Overflow is geared towards *coding* questions specifically (i.e. why is this code not working, or how do I change my code to achieve this thing, etc).